# ModHeader chrome extension does not send headers to custom extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I would like to use ModHeader chrome extension in order to send headers into my custom chrome extension - is it possible?
Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: You can use [cross-extension messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external). P.S. It's unclear what's so special about ModHeaders. Since you're writing an extension anyway, you can process headers yourself so you won't need ModHeader.

Comment: @wOxxOm I want to use ModHeader since I want to leverage its functionality in all cases - making request via web browser and via extension